# React Native (IOS), how to create a view that scrolls?

Tags: ios, react-native, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple app that simply lists a bunch of information on the screen.

Right now the app is just made up of a container View and then Views and Texts inside of it.

Once there is enough info on the screen that it fills up the whole screen in the simulator, the other info is hidden - I can't scroll to it.

How do I enable scrolling? I've tried fixing the height of the container and also changing it to a ScrollView, both with no luck.

Comment: have u viewed documentation for `ScrollView`? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html .. Use `scrollEnabled` property to enable scroll.

Comment: I did read through it - I just assumed it was set to true by default (im very new to IOS). That was it, thank you very much, iAnum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iAnum answered it in a comment, I needed to set scorllEnabled to true.